# Question about Norm and Trace of field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am confused about a line in Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory: "We return to the integrally closed integral domain $A$ with field of fractions $K$, and to its integral closure $B$ in the finite separable extension $L/K$. If $x\in B$ is an integral element of $L$, then all of its conjugates $\sigma x$ are also integral. Taking into account that $A$ is integrally closed, i.e., $A=B\cap K$, (2.6) implies that $Tr_{L/K}(x),N_{L/K}(x)\in A$" and where (2.6) states: "If $L/K$ is a separable extension and $\sigma:L\rightarrow\overline{K}$ varies over the different $K$-embeddings of $L$ into an algebraic closure $\overline{K}$ of $K$, then we have $f_x(t)=\prod_\sigma(t-\sigma x)$, $Tr_{L/K}(x)=\sum_\sigma \sigma x$, and $N_{L/K}(x)=\prod_\sigma \sigma x$."

My question is, why do the norm and trace lie in $A$? I understand that $B$ consists of the elements of $L$ that are integral over $A$. But since $A$ is only assumed to be integrally closed in $K$ (for which $L$ is an extension), then I don't see why the norm and trace should lie in $A$, especially since the conjugates of $x$ lie in $\overline{K}$ and not $K$. What am I missing?

Comment: The norm and trace lie in $K$ and are integral over $A$.

Comment: Right, the norm and trace lie in $K$, and since $A$ is integrally closed over $K$, then must in fact lie in $A$. Thanks

Comment: To show that $f(t)=\prod_\sigma(t-\sigma x)\subset K[t]$ you need the fixed field stuffs. Let $N$ be the normal closure of $L/K$, then $K= N^{Aut(N/K)}$ the subfield of $N$ fixed by $Aut(N/K)$, assume it is not the case, then $N^{Aut(N/K)}$ is larger than $K$, take $a\in N^{Aut(N/K)},\not \in K$, since $N/K$ is separable then is a distinct $K$-conjugate $b$, then $\sigma: K(a)\to K(b)$ extends to $\sigma : N\to \sigma(N)=N$ and $a$ is not fixed by $\sigma$, contradiction. Since the coefficients of $f$ are in the fixed subfield then $f\in K[t]$.